# undefined reference to `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)

Tags: c++, qt, root-framework

I want to use root cern libs in my Qt program. But I have problems with linker:

> undefined reference to `TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)

I don't know what's the reason. I did read another forum, but still can't understand the issue. Please, help me.

The `.pro` file contents:

```
QT += core
QT -= gui

CONFIG += c++11

TARGET = v_root_trees_2
CONFIG += console
CONFIG -= app_bundle

TEMPLATE = app

SOURCES += main.cpp

INCLUDEPATH += "C:/root_v5.34.34/include"

LIBS += -L"C:/root_v5.34.34/lib"  \
-lcomplexDict \
-ldequeDict \
-lfreetype \
-llibAfterImage \
-llibASImage \
-llibASImageGui \
-llibCint \
-llibCintex \
-llibCore \
-llibEG \
-llibEGPythia8 \
-llibEve \
-llibFitPanel \
-llibFoam \
-llibFTGL \
-llibFumili \
-llibGdml \
-llibGed \
-llibGenetic \
-llibGenVector \
-llibGeom \
-llibGeomBuilder \
-llibGeomPainter \
-llibGLEW \
-llibGpad \
-llibGraf \
-llibGraf3d \
-llibGui \
-llibGuiBld \
-llibGuiHtml \
-llibGviz3d \
-llibHist \
-llibHistPainter \
-llibHtml \
-llibMathCore \
-llibMathMore \
-llibMatrix \
-llibMinuit \
-llibMinuit2 \
-llibMLP \
-llibNet \
-llibPhysics \
-llibPostscript \
-llibProof \
-llibProofDraw \
-llibProofPlayer \
-llibPyROOT \
-llibQuadp \
-llibRecorder \
-llibReflex \
-llibReflexDict \
-llibRGL \
-llibRHTTP \
-llibRint \
-llibRIO \
-llibRODBC \
-llibRooFit \
-llibRooFitCore \
-llibRooStats \
-llibRootAuth \
-llibSessionViewer \
-llibSmatrix \
-llibSpectrum \
-llibSpectrumPainter \
-llibSPlot \
-llibSQLIO \
-llibTable \
-llibThread \
-llibTMVA \
-llibTree \
-llibTreePlayer \
-llibTreeViewer \
-llibUnuran \
-llibVMC \
-llibWin32gdk \
-llibXMLIO \
-llistDict \
-lmap2Dict \
-lmapDict \
-lmathtext \
-lmultimap2Dict \
-lmultimapDict \
-lmultisetDict \
-lsetDict \
-lvectorDict
```

main.cpp file:

```
#include <QCoreApplication>

#include "TMultiGraph.h" // problem if add this line

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    return a.exec();
}
```

I don't know what is wrong. I added all `.lib` files. 
The paths `C:/root_v5.34.34/lib` and `C:/root_v5.34.34/include` are correct and do exist. Changing paths I see `cannot find ...` error.
So, the paths are correct.

I checked the similar code in VS2013 and don't see any errors.
But I write a lot of code in Qt and can't change IDE. 
I understand, that some link causes the error, but can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

Some libraries in your project are included incorrectly. e.g. **-llibAfterImage -llibASImage -llibASImageGui**
you should write **-lAfterImage -lASImage -lASImageGui** and so on...
When i corrected your .pro file, build succeeded.
Possibly one of that incorrectly included libraries contains implementation of **TVersionCheck::TVersionCheck(int)**

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling for this problem recently. It's because that ROOT under windows is 32bit, and you need to check the MSCV2015 32bit while reinstalling Qt...